# Issue in Calling WebService by jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a an asp.net Webservice which i want to call by Jquery Ajax but on Executing i am getting `500 Internal Server Error` and in the Response i am getting `{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: Name.","StackTrace":"` on seeing the output in Browser Developer tool(Firebug).
Here is my Webservice code..

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class DateWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

HttpRequest request;

public DateWebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string GetData(string name, string contact, string email) {

    string Name = request[name];
    string Contact = request[contact];
    string Email = request[email];

    return Name+Contact+Email;
}    
}
```

and here is my jquery Ajax Code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#Button1").click(function() {


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ASPNET_WebServices_JQuery/DateWebService.asmx/GetData",
                data: { 'Name': 'SRI', 'Contact': '787979879898', 'Email': 'hr@.com' },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    $("#output").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Please help me to resolve this issue..Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[WebMethod]
public   string GetData(string Name, string Contact, string Email) {

               return Name+Contact+Email;
}
```

Store your string values to local variables then try like below

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ASPNET_WebServices_JQuery/DateWebService.asmx/GetData",
                    data: '{"Name":"' + Name + '","Contact":"' + Contact + '","Email":"' + Email + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg)
                    {
                        $("#output").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: `Unknown web method GetData` error on putting `static`

Comment: remove static and try like this  data: JSON.stringify({Name: "SRI"},etc..),  , put a breakpoints inside method and check its called or not, if it is not called then check it is working with out using any arguments

Comment: `JSON.stringify({Name: "SRI"},etc..)` you want me to replace in Ajax Call ..?

Comment: yes replace in ajax call, if it is also not working then remove argumets from function and remove post data from ajax and try it is working or not

Comment: I did the same and Now its Working and Even Breakpoint is getting hit ..But I want to Transfer Data also .Why it is not Happening for Data Transfer?

Comment: problem is in your transferred.

Comment: did u try this ? JSON.stringify({Name: "SRI",etc..},)

Comment: ok u just save your string values to local variable and try to post like this  data: '{"Name":"' + Name + '","Contact":"' + Contact + '","Email":"' + Email + '"}', its works fine for me ,just check it too

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this...

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetData(string Name, string Contact, string Email) {
        return Name+Contact+Email;
    }


$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ASPNET_WebServices_JQuery/DateWebService.asmx/GetData",
                data: "{ 'Name': 'SRI', 'Contact': '787979879898', 'Email': 'hr@.com' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    $("#output").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line from you ajax code and it will work:

```js
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```